# Is the only way to "polymorphically" declare a member of a non-specialized template type, by defining a base class?

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11, polymorphism

Suppose we have a templated class,

```
template<typename Type>
class Container {};
```

Of course, we can't do this:

```
struct Foo
{
    Container _container;
}
```

But what if we wanted to do something like it? Is the *only* way to do this, to define a base class,

```
class ContainerBase {};

template<typename Type>
class Container : public ContainerBase {};
```

and store a pointer, like below?

```
struct Foo
{
    ContainerBase* _container;
}
```

It's simple enough, but it feels weird to have to add a base class solely for that reason, when it seems the compiler should have enough information to imply a set of related specializations. Of course, regardless `_container` needs to be a pointer, else `Foo` couldn't resolve to a static size, but

```
struct Foo
{
    Container* _container;
}
```

doesn't work either.

Comment: Also, is there name for such an empty base class, existing solely for this reason?

Comment: "Of course, we can't do this" What you mean? Of course you can do that (barring the missing template argument).

Comment: "Barring the missing template argument." But that's exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: You mean something like `Container<Foo> _container;` Yes you can do that.

Comment: I precisely _don't_ want to specify `<foo>` and instead allow my struct to store any specialization.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - Woops, thanks for the edit.

Comment: "But what if we wanted to do something like it?" <- You're question is confusing to me.  You obviously are expecting a kind of behavior and asking if you can implement it, but I don't quite understand what it is you're asking.  If you want to point to a common base, of course you'd have to add a common base.  Can you explain what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: I guess I'm asking if there already exists a common base by the fact that template specializations are clearly related to the template class itself. I was wondering if there's a way to refer to such an "implied" base rather than creating an empty base class, which seems somewhat superfluous.

Comment: If you don't want to derive, there's always `void*` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it seems the compiler should have enough information to imply a set of related specializations.

Nope. Template specializations are totally unrelated except in name, and the name of a type has essentially no bearing on runtime operation. Specializations of a given template usually share a (mostly) common interface, but they could just as well be completely different.

Adding a base class is essential if you want to relate between the specializations. And if they share so much in common, factoring that functionality into the base is a pretty great idea.

Comment: Ah! Okay. Your edit, _"Specializations of the same template usually share a (mostly) common interface, but they could just as well be completely different,"_ made me realize the impossibility.

Comment: Actually, could you clear something up for me? I'm trying to think of a concrete example. Initially, I understood what you were saying as, `Container<int>` and `Container<double>` can implement different interfaces, meaning different methods—and if that were true, I see completely why a non-specialized member (or pointer) is impossible. But how would you implement different methods between the two specializations in the first place? Can you actually implement something like `void Container<int>::doSomethingSpecificallyForIntegers() {}`? If so, then I see your point.

Comment: @AndrewCheong By using explicit specializations. `template<> class Container<int> { void doSomethingSpecificallyForIntegers(){} };`

Comment: @AndrewCheong Yep, you can put anything you like into the `class` body of any template (partial) specialization definition. Merely being a template adds zero requirements to the definition of a class. The term [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) captures the gist, although templates are essentially a pure-functional, totally untyped system. "Concepts," a major feature of the upcoming C++17 standard, seeks to get such ducks all in a row.